# Recommended Textbook(s) for Real Analysis and Measure Theory for Beginners

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, book-recommendation

I'm planning to learn real analysis (i.e. Lesbegue measure, measure theory; not mathematical analysis), and would like to have some textbook recommended (for beginners). I've studied basic mathematical analysis using Baby Rudin.

Our school uses $\textit{Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions}$ written by Evans, which I thought is extremely beginner unfriendly; also I don't quite like the style of Rudin's book, so I'd rather not to use his $\textit{Real and Complex Analysis}$. Other than these two, are there any recommendations? Thanks in advance.

Comment: not mathematical analysis?

Comment: @Snoop I mean not the very basic mathematical analysis, i.e. not limit, continuity, Riemann integration, etc, but instead focus on measure theory

Comment: @Left Hand I highly recommend the book "Measure, integration and real analysis" by Sheldon Axler which is also an open access book, freely available from the author's website.

Comment: @lorenzo I second your suggestion. I don't think there exists a better book that fits the purposes of the OP.

Comment: @lorenzo Thanks for the suggestion; I'll check it out.

Comment: @QuantumSpace Seems good; I'll check it out.

Comment: measure theory IS mathematical analysis. A very good book about measure theory is the book of Donald Cohn

Comment: Bartle's 'The elements of integration and Lebesgue measure' is a pretty good book. And, at least in my opinion, it has low pre requirements to follow.